# Batch type duplicates lines

Tags: batch-file, merge, duplicate-data

Below code works like a chart except that when I open the target file each line appears typed twice! I deleted the target file and checked many times. I'm not running it twice.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "sourcelocation=\\whatever\Outbox\"
set targetlocation="G:\whatever\SharedData\\"
set "tmplocation=C:\tmpmerges\\"
set refdate=20151113
set versionID=000001
set entity=WTV
echo ...merging files
for %%f in (!tmplocation!*_WTVS_*!refdate!*_V!versionID!.txt) do type "%%f" >> !tmplocation!S_!entity!_WTVS_!refdate!_V!versionID!.txt
echo file merge completed
pause
```

Comment: The `for` wildcard `!tmplocation!*_WTVS_*` also catches the files used in the output redirection `!tmplocation!S_!entity!_WTVS_` so those file are doubled.

Comment: I just did some quick testing and I think if you just use a FOR /F command an execute the DIR command within the FOR /F you should be OK.  I believe with FOR /F it loads all the output of the command into memory first before it begins processing the output of the command.

Comment: @Squashman. tried but not sure how to implement your suggestion. The way around to do: `for %%f in (!tmplocation!*_WTVS_*!refdate!*_V!versionID!.txt) do type "%%f" >> !tmplocation!Merged\S_!entity!_WTVS_!refdate!_V!versionID!.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Not really understanding why you are using delayed expansion for all your variables. But you can try this with your FOR command.

```
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b "!tmplocation!*_WTVS_*!refdate!*_V!versionID!.txt"') do type "%%~f" >> !tmplocation!S_!entity!_WTVS_!refdate!_V!versionID!.txt
```

Comment: this is giving a 'cant find the file'. will study or solution and try to implement latter.

Comment: @BuckTurgidson, should work just like a standard FOR command.  I can't see how you are trying to implement it, so there is no way for me to troubleshoot it for you.